# Is 'you might look but won't see' correct?

Tags: word-choice

When your eyes are open but your mind closed, you might look but won't see.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is drawing a distinction between the physical act of "looking" versus the deeper, more intellectual and spiritual act of "seeing". 
The author is asking people to not just observe the world thoughtlessly, but to think about and try to understand what you see and experience.